# Do we have to precompose to call it a pushforward?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, chain-rule

I've been trying to perform some calculations that would benefit from being phrased in a geometric manner. A lot of the time I have something like:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h \circ g_t = \frac{\partial h}{\partial g_t}\dot{g}_t$$

Where $h,g_t$ are diffeomorphisms and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial g_t}$ denotes the Jacobian. I want to say this is simply just the pushforward of the map $h$ acting on the tangent vector $\dot{g}_t$, i.e. $h_* \dot{g}_t$ and this fits with my intuition that the pushforward is essentially the Jacobian when it comes to flat space. But when I go to verify my intuition with what the definition of pushforward is this doesn't seem correct. For example, according to:

[Pushforward of a Vector Field by a Diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730603/pushforward-of-a-vector-field-by-a-diffeomorphism)

[Show that the chain rule $(G\circ F)_* = G_* \circ F_*$ holds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973091/show-that-the-chain-rule-g-circ-f-g-circ-f-holds)

[Identity about composition of the push forward of diffeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057782/identity-about-composition-of-the-push-forward-of-diffeomorphisms)

I should be saying that it's not a pushforward unless I had something like $\frac{\partial h}{\partial g_t}\dot{g}_t h^{-1}$. How come? I find it very disconcerting that such a natural operating such as the chain rule doesn't translate to the pushforward map. Is there any way I can make it more "geometric"?

Comment: It is important to distinguish between the concepts of pushfoward and derivative of a diffeomorphism. Given a diffeomorphism $f:M\to N$ the derivative $Tf$ is a map $TM\to TN$ which covers $f$. The pushforward is a map $\mathfrak{X}(M)\to \mathfrak{X}(N)$ which is the identification of sections of $TM$ with sections of $TN$ by $Tf$. The pushforward has to change to domain of a vector field and hence requires us to precompose with $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Are you saying that there's a distinction between the tangent map and a pushforward? I was not aware of this subtlety, do you have a reference on something that really outlines the difference with a fine comb and compares them in coordinates? A lot of textbooks just state an abstract formula by itself which is why I get mixed up like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept I was looking for was the notion of the tangent map. This is multiplying by the Jacobian matrix, without the change of coordinates that is part of the pushforward. My confusion arises from the fact that the terminology is mixed often. What Wikipedia calls the "pushforward differential" is the tangent map, and is an inequivalent operation to the pushforward discussed in the linked questions.

The book of Marsden and Ratiu on Tensor Analysis covers this.